# Getting ErrorAccessDenied when trying to select my own properties

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get all of the properties for my user account using

```
var me = await graphClient
    .Me
    .Request()
    .Select("AboutMe, AccountEnabled, AdditionalData, AssignedLicenses, AssignedPlans, Birthday, BusinessPhones, Calendar, CalendarGroups, CalendarView, Calendars, City, CompanyName, ContactFolders, Contacts, Country, CreatedObjects, Department, DirectReports, DisplayName, Drive, Drives, Events, GivenName, HireDate, Id, InferenceClassification, Interests, JobTitle, Mail, MailFolders, MailNickname, MailboxSettings, Manager, MemberOf, Messages, MobilePhone, MySite, ODataType, OfficeLocation, OnPremisesImmutableId, OnPremisesLastSyncDateTime, OnPremisesSecurityIdentifier, OnPremisesSyncEnabled, OwnedDevices, OwnedObjects, PasswordPolicies, PasswordProfile, PastProjects, Photo, PostalCode, PreferredLanguage, PreferredName, ProvisionedPlans, ProxyAddresses, RegisteredDevices, Responsibilities, Schools, Skills, State, StreetAddress, Surname, UsageLocation, UserPrincipalName, UserType")
    .GetAsync();
```

But I'm getting

> "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."

How is this possible? Surely I should have access to my own information?

Which properties specifically would I not have access to, and why?

Does anyone know if this information is documented anywhere?

Appreciate any guidance

---

My application always runs as a logged in user, and has delegated permissions `User.Read` and `User.ReadBasic.All`

Answer (score 0):

What permissions (scopes) have been granted to your application? Please provide more information.

In the meantime, please take a look at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference and https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_get.

Another common mistake is to request an access token using `client_credentials` flow (i.e. application-only context), and then trying to call `../me` which requires a signed-in user.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Hi Dan thanks for your answer. I updated my question

Comment: Can you also paste in the FULL error message, containing the client request id and the timestamp please?  Also which flow are you using to acquire a token?  Also you can take a look at the access token by decoding it here https://jwtinspect.azurewebsites.net/ to check it looks right and contains the scope claims you are expecting (in the scp parameter).